# Quadratic equation solver outputting in unknown format

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a quadratic equation solver, but for some reason my program is giving me answers in an unknown format.

I entered the simple quadratic equation x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0, expecting my program to give x = -1 or x = -1, but instead it gave x = 0138151E or x = 0138152D. It looks like it outputs these values for x for any inputs (not recognizing unreal answers and catching them). Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities_revised.h"

class Imaginary {};

double square(int a)
{
    return a * a;
}

double quadratic_solver_pos(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double radicand = square(b) - 4 * a * c;
    if (radicand < 0) throw Imaginary{};
    x = (-b + sqrt(radicand)) / (2 * a);
    return x;
}

double quadratic_solver_neg(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double radicand = square(b) - 4 * a * c;
    if (radicand < 0) throw Imaginary{};
    x = (-b - sqrt(radicand)) / (2 * a);
    return x;
}

int main()
try {
    cout << "This program is a quadratic equation solver.\n";
    cout << "Quadratic equations are of the form: ax^2 + bx + c = 0\n";
    cout << "Enter a, b, and c, respectively:\n";
    double a = 0; 
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << "Your quadratic equation: " << a << "x^2 + " << b << "x + " << c << " = 0\n";
    cout << "x = " << quadratic_solver_pos << " or x = " << quadratic_solver_neg << '\n';
}
catch (Imaginary) {
    cout << "x is unreal\n";
}
```

Comment: Why are you printing out the addresses of your functions instead of *calling* the functions?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need to call the function.  `cout << "x = " << quadratic_solver_pos << ...` becomes `cout << "x = " << quadratic_solver_pos(a, b, c) << ...`

Comment: BTW, remove the `square` function and replace the calls with `(x * x)`.  No need to call a function for a simple operation.

Comment: Having two functions `quadratic_solver_pos` and `quadratic_solver_neg` also seem redundant. With all due respect, but a well written function handles both cases.

Comment: Also: Should I dare and ask what `#include "../std_lib_facilities_revised.h"` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass your variables to your functions.

You need to do it like so `quadratic_solver_pos(a, b, c);`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that.